# Compiling Boost within the Visual Studio build process

Tags: visual-studio, boost, bjam

What is the easiest way to attach a Boost separately compiled library to a Visual Studio 2012 project or solution so that someone with Boost source can build the library during the VS build? This is to make the whole of Boost available on demand.

Comment: What Boost libraries do you need to build? If it's something lightweight like `Boost.System`, you can just include the appropriate cpp(s) into your VS project.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different strategies. I personally use [BlueGo](http://vertexwahn.de/bluego.html)

[image]

BlueGo can build different Boost versions for different Visual Studio versions. You can specify different modules that should be build.